# Python - Delete row in matrix/array if row contains

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

If you have an x*n matrix how do you check for a row that contains a certain number and if so, how do you delete that row?

Comment: A row that contains a certain number in a specific column or in any column?

Comment: Any column, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `pandas`, you can create a mask that you can use to index the dataframe, negating the mask with `~`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4))
#    0  1   2   3
# 0  0  1   2   3
# 1  4  5   6   7
# 2  8  9  10  11

value = 2
```

If you want to check if the value is contained in a specific column:

```
df[~(df[2] == value)]
#    0  1   2   3
# 1  4  5   6   7
# 2  8  9  10  11
```

Or if it can be contained in any column:

```
df[~(df == value).any(axis=1)]
#    0  1   2   3
# 1  4  5   6   7
# 2  8  9  10  11
```

Just reassign it to `df` afterwards.

---

This also works if you are using just `numpy`:

```
x = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
#        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

x[~(x == value).any(axis=1)]
# array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
#        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

---

And finally, if you are using plain Python and have a list of lists, use the built-in `any` in a list comprehension:

```
y = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]

[row for row in y if not any(x == value for x in row)]
# [[4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

Comment: A very good answer! Could not have been better and more elaborate, hope you get other upvotes from other than me, thanks!